# How to stop form execution without using prevent default?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My form is a payment gateway integration form. 
I need to save details to the database first, then only need to send the details to the payment gateway. 
When I submit the form I need to check it's validity with some php operation. After doing the php operation I need to actually submit the form.

Can you suggest a good method to solve this?

This is my form

```
<form method="post" action="paymentgatway url " id="myForm">

<input type="text" name="name1" requried>
<input type="text" name="cash" requried>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="submit">
</form>
```

and PHP

```
var $myForm = $('#myForm');
    if ($myForm[0].checkValidity()) {
     <?php some php code ?>

     then submit the form 

    }   
    else{

          $myForm.find(':submit').click();

    }
```

Comment: `php` code will not execute after `JavaScript` condition..

Comment: @RayonDabre It will in the case of using php templates. But I don't know whether OP using the same or not.

Comment: 1: Php runs on the server. 2: Never call anything `name="submit"` if you plan to submit it using JavaScript later

Comment: Agree with you @Mr_Green but do not think OP is dealing with template as he is validating form first..

Comment: What exactly your "PHP code" is supposed to be doing? It won't work the way you show us, as per the @RayonDabre's comment.

Comment: you need to look into AJAX - why tag the question if you did not try it?

Comment: @mplungjan could you please give an example .

Comment: No. There are THOUSAND of examples here at SO. Please do some research: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%5Bajax%5D+submit+after+ajax+validation

Answer (score 2):

You can change input type submit to input type button.It won't submit your form.
On click of that button you can have your php check using ajax.
after success response, you can submit the form using script $('#myForm').submit();

Comment: after removing "name="submit"

Answer (score 0):

There's no way using natural submit events. You may  using a button with a click event that trigger a submit.